# How can I see the icons inside the SVG file?

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to see all the icons inside the SVG file. I have tried to insert it into the HTML file with an img tag but I see a blank page.

```html
<svg aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
<symbol id="icon-triangle-left" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
<title>triangle-left</title>
<path d="M14 5v10l-9-5 9-5z"></path>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-triangle-right" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
<title>triangle-right</title>
<path d="M15 10l-9 5v-10l9 5z"></path>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-check" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
<title>check</title>
<path d="M8.294 16.998c-0.435 0-0.847-0.203-1.111-0.553l-3.573-4.721c-0.465-0.613-0.344-1.486 0.27-1.951 0.615-0.467 1.488-0.344 1.953 0.27l2.351 3.104 5.911-9.492c0.407-0.652 1.267-0.852 1.921-0.445s0.854 1.266 0.446 1.92l-6.984 11.21c-0.242 0.391-0.661 0.635-1.12 0.656-0.022 0.002-0.042 0.002-0.064 0.002z"></path>
</symbol>
</defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: How about **not** ensuring that there are zero pixels to render the icons on? `width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden; `

Comment: Changed it to style="position: absolute; width: 100; height: 100;" . Did not help.

Comment: That CSS is invalid. Non-zero lengths request units.

Comment: Your icons are all `<symbols>`. you need to use them like this: `<svg viewbox="0 0 20 20">
  <use xlink:href="#icon-check"/>
</svg>` Also you may need to give the svg element a width

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided contains only `<symbols>`. This is used to house SVG definitions that can be reused in different parts of the document. You would use them like this:

```
<svg>
    <use xlink:href="#icon-triangle-left" />
</svg>
```

Live test: https://codepen.io/guilhermemuller/pen/NWqddGp

Comment: Good explanation. Thank you!